# haskell conduits from file to process

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, conduit

How can I stream from a file into process?

```
Data.Conduit.Binary.sourceFile :: MonadResource m => FilePath -> Producer m ByteString
Data.Conduit.Process.sourceProcessWithStreams :: CreateProcess -> Producer IO ByteString -> Consumer ByteString IO a -> Consumer ByteString IO b -> IO (ExitCode, a, b)
```

The only thing that is a `MonadResource` is a `ResourceT`, in particular `IO` is not a `MonadResource`.

I can see that there's `sourceHandle` which is `IO`, but I would rather not handle my own file opens and closes if possible. Also, I want to understand this problem in case I understand it in another space.

There's also `Data.Conduit.Lift.distribute`:

```
distribute :: (Monad (t (ConduitM b o m)), Monad m, Monad (t m), MonadTrans t, MFunctor t) => ConduitM b o (t m) () -> t (ConduitM b o m) ()
```

so I'd get something like

```
distribute $ sourceFile "foo" :: ResourceT (ConduitM i ByteString IO) ()
```

but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: What are you streaming ? And to which process ? And overall what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I fixed up my answer.

Comment: Nothing that you'll be able to cook up will be nearly as simple as using `sourceHandle` and closing the handle yourself. `ResourceT` is nice, but it really is just a convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to supply a `CreateProcess` you can redirect stdin from a known file name either using the redirection capabilities of `CreateProcess` or even the shell.

Here are some examples. Note that in each case `wc` reports the
stats for the file `input` and not the supplied Producer (which
is the empty Producer.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack runghc --resolver lts-6.0
    --package conduit-extra
    --package conduit-combinators
 -}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Conduit
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Process
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

ex1 = do x <- sourceCmdWithConsumer "date" lengthC
         print x

emit prefix = mapM_C (\x -> BS.putStr prefix >> BS.putStr ": " >> BS.putStrLn x)

ex2 = do let cp = shell "wc < input"
         x <- sourceProcessWithConsumer cp (emit "stdout")
         print x

ex3 = sourceCmdWithStreams "wc < input" (return ())  (emit "stdout") (emit "stderr")

ex4 = do let cp = shell "wc < input"
         sourceProcessWithStreams cp (return ()) (emit "stdout") (emit "stderr" )
```

**Update**

If you want to avoid spawning a shell, I've created an alternate version
of sourceProcessWithStreams which takes stdin from the CreateProcess:

[Using UseProvidedHandle with streamingProcess](https://gist.github.com/erantapaa/944b690ec0a5dedc988a9be54e958712)

Alternatively, you can use `withFile` and `sourceHandle`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack runghc --resolver lts-6.0
    --package streaming-commons
    --package conduit
    --package conduit-extra
 -}

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Conduit
import System.Process
import Data.Conduit.Process

emit prefix = mapM_C $ \x -> BS.putStr prefix >> BS.putStr ": " >> BS.putStrLn x

ex3 = do let cp = (proc "wc" [])
         withFile "input" ReadMode $ \h -> do
           sourceProcessWithStreams cp (sourceHandle h) (emit "stdout") (emit "stderr")

main = ex3 >>= print
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Concerning the original answer, I guess didn't mention it explicitly (I supposed it was implicit in the heading), but I need a whole conduit line because I need to process the data between input and output. The file and process are merely the beginning and end. Concerning your update, I already said I would prefer not to us sourceHandle if possible because I would prefer not to handle my own file opens and closes if possible.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to send the contents of the input file through another conduit stage before piping it to the process?